# Increment with constraints? Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a health variable, that when a player is damaged or healed it needs to increase or decrease health.

The default solution would be to just do a find, subtract from or add to health then set. But this wouldn't be atomic and a request for damage or heal could come between the find and set, making the values wrong.

So to do this atomically, find and update/modify with inc operator could work except for the fact you can't damage to negatives or heal over a max. So I need a way to constrain an increment. IS it possible?

The only other solution I thought of is to queue heal and damage in an array with push and pull operators but I'm worried that arrays rapid growth would have performance issues and I would need to aggregate it constantly to get current health.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the Update If Current pattern to work around concurrency issues.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/update-if-current/

Basically you're making an update call, but the query for which document to apply the update to includes the old value you're updating. Something like the following:

```
function damagePlayer(username, done) {
  var player = db.players.findOne( { username: username } );

  if ( player ) {
     var oldHealth = myDocument.health;
     var health = oldHealth - 1;
     if(health < 0) {
       health = 0;
     }

     var results = db.products.update({
        _id: player._id,
        health: oldHealth
      },{
        $set: { health: health }
      });

     if ( results.hasWriteError() ) {
        // This probably means that the health was updated while we were 
        // fetching the data to update. Just need to run this process 
        // again to re-apply the update.
        return process.nextTick(damagePlayer.bind(this, username, done));
     }

     done();
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks really promising! Thanks. My only concern would be some sort of infinite recursive  loop here so I might add a count here...